# using a decimal in my element's name

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use *two-way data binding* to get the value of my input but I'm having trouble using a "." in my input name:

```
<form name="signInForm">
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <input name="user.email" data-ng-model="user.email" type="email" placeholder="user@email.net">
    </label>
</form>
{{ signInForm.user.email }}
```

How do I get my value out?

Comment: Just use `{{user.email}}` in your template. Remember to initialize the user object in your controller: `$scope.user = {...}`. Am I missing something here or did someone not even glipse through the docs? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented:
You need to use:

```
{{user.email}}
```

Instead of

```
{{ signInForm.user.email }}
```

Comment: I ended up using `{{ signInForm['user.email'] }}` for what I needed